# Setup custom config.json location for Grunt tasks in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gruntjs

I want to run my Grunt tasks (through a GruntFile.js file) in my IntelliJ IDEA. However, the config.json is located somewhere else which is causing the loading of the GruntFile.js to crash.

Is there a way to set the –-config.json parameter? Or is there a work around? It seems that I only can configure the environment variables and node options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We configured a custom environment variable. It works beautifully.

```
grunt.option('config.json') || process.env.BS_CONFIG_JSON|| 'build/config.json'
```

[image]